# Parent directory listing at root directory

Tags: linux

As we all know. Every Unix directories contains special directories- current(.) & parent(..). Also top level root directory in Unix is called " / ".

When I tried at root directory,

```
  $ ls -ia
         2 .                    
         2 .. 
      3963 bin

...............
```

both (.) & (..) has same inode number

& executing

```
$ cd ..
```

at root directory ends at the same location.

My question is why does even root directory contains special directory listing (..)? What is the need to list (..) at root directory?

Comment: Is **consistency** a good enough reason?

Comment: Duplication of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125972/cd-on-root-folder and agree with codeforester, choices were made in UNIX file-system way back, that this is a desirable increase in uniformity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, **it's just there to keep the convention consistent**.

---

According to POSIX defintion

[**3.144 Empty Directory**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html)

> A directory that contains, at most, directory entries for dot and
>   dot-dot, and has exactly one link to it (other than its own dot entry,
>   if one exists), in dot-dot. This definition is repeated with different
>   phrasings in the POSIX descriptions of all file-commands.

From Superuser [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/804162/why-does-the-root-directory-have-a-reference-to-its-parent):

> This above convoluted definition for an Empty Directory is apparently
>   behind this funny convention, and its purpose is to avoid any
>   exceptions to the rule, not even for slash (/) i.e. root dir.

Comment: One more answer I got from google is in early ages concept of networked unix or unix like system was there. So /hostname was thought to be root directory. In such network we can access other unix systems using path /hostname.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Unix standard for directories.  All directories have an entry for themselves (.) as well as the parent (..).  These special entries would be used for directory traversal.  With the "keep it simple" policy, root directory has the same basic structure like any other directory.